# Optimisation of For loop in nested loops in a MPI program

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, mpi

I have nested loops in the code attached. I want to optimise the interior most for loop (ks_div one).

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
proc_id = comm.Get_rank()
n_procs = comm.Get_size()

import time
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.scimath import sqrt
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from joblib import Parallel, delayed

delta = 10.0;
lund = 1e04;
alpha = 1e-7;
g = 10.0;
eta = 1.0;
VA = lund*eta/delta;
k0 = sqrt(6)/(1.0*delta);
Omega = VA*k0*50/(1.0*sqrt(2));
ratio = 500000.0;
beta = 1e05;#VA*VA*k0*k0/(g*alpha*ratio*ratio);
t0 = VA*VA/(1.0*g*alpha*beta*eta)
t_min = -8
t_max = 10
division =50
tym =np.logspace(t_min,t_max,division)
t11 = 4*Omega*Omega/(1.0*eta*VA**2*k0**4);
ks_max = 100.0/(1.0*delta);
kz_max = 100.0/(1.0*delta);
ks_min = 1e-10;
kz_min = 1e-10;     

kz_div = 1000001
ks_div = 5001
div = ks_div*kz_div;
ks_inc = (ks_max-ks_min)/(1.0*ks_div)#increment in ks
kz_inc = (kz_max-kz_min)/(1.0*kz_div)#increment in kz

start = time.time()


work_size = (kz_div) // n_procs
extra_work = (kz_div) % n_procs
my_work = work_size + (1 if proc_id<extra_work else 0)
d_start = work_size * proc_id + (proc_id if proc_id<extra_work else extra_work)
d_end = d_start + my_work


for s in range(len(tym)):
  norm = 0;
  normk = 0;
  normks = 0;
  normkz = 0;
  counter = 0;


  for l in range(d_start, d_end):



        for i in range(int(ks_div)):

            ks1 = ks_min+i*ks_inc
            kz1 = kz_min+l*kz_inc         



            ks = ks1 #np.ravel(ks1)
            kz = kz1 #np.ravel(kz1) #, kz = np.meshgrid(ks_inc,kz_inc)
            k = sqrt(ks**2+kz**2);


            omgM = VA*kz;
            omge = eta*k**2;
            omgA = sqrt(g * alpha*beta)*ks/k;
            omgO = Omega*kz/k;
            a1 = 1j*1;
            a2 = 2*omge;
            a3 = -1j*(omgA**2+omge**2+2*omgM**2+4*omgO**2);
            a4 = -2*omge*(omgA**2+omgM**2+4*omgO**2);
            a5 = 1j*(omgM**4+omgA**2*(omge**2+omgM**2)+4*omge**2*omgO**2);
            a6 = omgA**2*omge*omgM**2;

            eqn =[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6];
            roots = np.roots(eqn);

            l4 = roots[0];
            l2 = roots[1];
            l3 = roots[2];
            l1 = roots[3];
            l5 = roots[4];


            t = tym[s]*t11
            theta0hat = delta**3.0/(16.0*np.pi*(2*np.pi)**(1.0/2.0)) * np.exp(- (delta**2)*(ks**2 + kz**2)/8.0)

            a11 = (alpha*g*ks/(1.0*k*k))*theta0hat;
            a22 = 0;
            a33 = -a11*(omgM*omgM+omgA*omgA+4*omgO*omgO);
            a44 = a11*omgM*omgM*omge;

            d1 = (l1-l2)*(l1-l3)*(l1-l4)*(l1-l5);
            d2 = (l2-l1)*(l2-l3)*(l2-l4)*(l2-l5);
            d3 = (l3-l1)*(l3-l2)*(l3-l4)*(l3-l5);
            d4 = (l4-l1)*(l4-l3)*(l4-l2)*(l4-l5);
            d5 = (l5-l1)*(l5-l3)*(l5-l2)*(l5-l4);

            n11 = a44
            n12 = -1j*a33*(l2+l3+l4+l5)
            n13 = -a22*(l4*l5+l3*l4+l3*l5+l2*l3+l2*l4+l2*l5)
            n14 = 1j*a11*(l2*l4*l5+l3*l4*l5+l2*l3*l4+l2*l3*l5)

            n22 = -1j*a33*(l1+l3+l4+l5)
            n23 = -a22*(l4*l5+l3*l4+l3*l5+l1*l3+l1*l4+l1*l5)
            n24 = 1j*a11*(l1*l4*l5+l3*l4*l5+l1*l3*l4+l1*l3*l5)

            n32 = -1j*a33*(l1+l2+l4+l5)
            n33 = -a22*(l4*l5+l2*l4+l2*l5+l1*l2+l1*l4+l1*l5)
            n34 = 1j*a11*(l1*l4*l5+l2*l4*l5+l1*l2*l4+l1*l2*l5)

            n42 = -1j*a33*(l1+l3+l2+l5)
            n43 = -a22*(l3*l5+l2*l3+l2*l5+l1*l2+l1*l3+l1*l5)
            n44 = 1j*a11*(l1*l3*l5+l2*l3*l5+l1*l2*l3+l1*l2*l5)

            n52 = -1j*a33*(l1+l3+l2+l4)
            n53 = -a22*(l3*l4+l2*l3+l2*l4+l1*l2+l1*l3+l1*l4)
            n54 = 1j*a11*(l1*l3*l4+l2*l3*l4+l1*l2*l3+l1*l2*l4)

            D1 = (n11+n12+n13+n14)/(1.0*d1)
            D2 = (n11+n22+n23+n24)/(1.0*d2)
            D3 = (n11+n32+n33+n34)/(1.0*d3)
            D4 = (n11+n42+n43+n44)/(1.0*d4)
            D5 = (n11+n52+n53+n54)/(1.0*d5)

            psihat = D5*np.exp(1j*l5*t)+D4*np.exp(1j*l4*t)+D2*np.exp(1j*l2*t)
            #print(psihat)       
            func = psihat*sqrt(ks**2+kz**2)
            func_ks = func*ks
            func_kz = func*kz
            func_k = func*sqrt(kz**2+ks**2)

            norm += np.real(sqrt(func*np.conj(func)));
            normk += np.real(sqrt(func_k*np.conj(func_k))); 
            normkz += np.real(sqrt(func_kz*np.conj(func_kz)));
            normks += np.real(sqrt(func_ks*np.conj(func_ks))); 

  norm_reduced = comm.reduce(norm, op=MPI.SUM, root=0)
  normk_reduced = comm.reduce(normk, op=MPI.SUM, root=0)
  normks_reduced = comm.reduce(normks, op=MPI.SUM, root=0)
  normkz_reduced = comm.reduce(normkz, op=MPI.SUM, root=0)

  if proc_id == 0:
     ksn = normks_reduced/norm_reduced
     kzn = normkz_reduced/norm_reduced
     kn = normk_reduced/norm_reduced

     en = eta*(kn**2)
     Mn = VA * kzn
     An = sqrt(g* alpha * beta* ksn**2/(1.0*kn**2))
     On = Omega*kzn/(1.0*kn)

     aa1 = 1j*1;
     aa2 = 2*en;
     aa3 = -1j*(An**2+en**2+2*Mn**2+4*On**2);
     aa4 = -2*en*(An**2+Mn**2+4*On**2);
     aa5 = 1j*(Mn**4+An**2*(en**2+Mn**2)+4*en**2*On**2);
     aa6 = An**2*en*Mn**2;

     eqn1 =[aa1,aa2,aa3,aa4,aa5,aa6];
     roots1 = np.roots(eqn1);

     L1 = 2*On+1j*en*Mn**2/(4*On**2);
     L3 = Mn*Mn/(2.0*On)+1j*en;
     L2 = -2*On+1j*en*Mn*Mn/(4*On*On);
     L4 = -Mn**2/(2.0*On)+1j*en;
     L5 = 1j*An*An*en/(Mn*Mn);

     ll4 = roots1[0];
     ll2 = roots1[1];
     ll3 = roots1[2];
     ll1 = roots1[3];
     ll5 = roots1[4];

     f = open("rot_norm_OMEGA_m.txt","a")
     f.write("%.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g\n"%(tym[s],On,Mn,An,en))
     f.close()

     p = open("rot_norm_imlambda_approx_m.txt","a")
     p.write("%.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g\n"%(np.imag(L1),np.imag(L2),np.imag(L3),np.imag(L4),np.imag(L5)))
     p.close()

     s = open("rot_norm_relambda_approx_m.txt","a")
     s.write("%.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g\n"%(np.real(L1),np.real(L2),np.real(L3),np.real(L4),np.real(L5)))
     s.close()

     q = open("rot_norm_imlambda_num_m.txt","a")
     q.write("%.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g\n"%(np.imag(ll2),np.imag(ll4),np.imag(ll1),np.imag(ll3),np.imag(ll5)))
     q.close() 

     q = open("rot_norm_relambda_num_m.txt","a")
     q.write("%.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g\n"%(np.real(ll2),np.real(ll4),np.real(ll1),np.real(ll3),np.real(ll5)))
     q.close()

     print ('Completion Time: {:2f}'.format(time.time()-start))
```

I can't vectorise it since the number of points are quite large. I am using np.roots which also makes it difficult to use a vectorise form. Please have a look and help me out here. I am basically calculating a L2 norm. It is taking a quite lot of time. I had given this code on a machine with 1440 cores and it took about 20 hours to print just one time step.

Thank you.

Comment: you are already doing the parallelization on the `l` loop that has 10 million iterations (vs 1440 cores). so assuming you are running flat mpi with 1440 cores, why do you think parallelizing the innermost loop will increase performance. also note you first "declare" `normk` as an array, and then use it as a scalar.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you for the feedback. I have made the corrections for normk. I don't want to parallelise the inner loop, I want to some how optimise it. It is a plain for loop right now. I don't know if it possible.

Comment: since the iterations are independent, and assuming you run flat mpi with all 1440 cores, you might only lose efficiency if there is some significant imbalance between tasks. Otherwise, I am afraid parallelization will not help you get better performance. Instead, you really want to make one iteration (much) faster. My advice would be to rewrite your program in `Fortran` or `C` to remove `python` (interpreter performance) from the equation, and let the compilers do their tricks at `-Ofast`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I have a similar code in C. It is very fast. However, I am finding roots of a quintic equation with complex coefficients in the code above (using np.roots). For that I don't have way to do in C. I have tried using some tricks there but they won't work.

Comment: you can use get the roots of a quintic equation https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/poly.html

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you for the link. I went through it but I don't think it calculates the roots of an equation with complex coefficients.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet How can we ascertain that the code that I have posted written in python is scalable?

Comment: There is no communication in the parallel part, so assuming this is the hotspot, that is pretty good. If your code is memory bound (vs cpu bound), intra socket scalability will be limited though.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you so much for discussing it. I am sorry for a late reply.